# How to identify the same web element from different sections div using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Consider I am having the same Link within different section div.

Link 1 position will be the dynamic and sometimes both the Link will be displayed within div1 and div 2. Sometimes Link 1 will display only within div 1 or it will display only within div2.

```
<section 1 ...
<div 1>
<a class....href="#">Link 1</a>
</div 1 >
</section 1>
<section 2 ...
<div 2>
<a class....href="#">Link 1</a>
</div 2 >
</section 2>
```

I need to achieve the below scenarios and I don't think Xpath will solve this problem, since this div will be the dynamic one.

**Scenario 1:**

When both the divs are present, then I need to click on the Link 1 from div2

**Scenario 2:**

Suppose if the Link1 is not present within div 1 , then `<a class....href="#">Link 1</a>` will not be visible. So, how should I confirm that only one link is present in case any one of the link 1 is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a common xpath

```
List<WebElement> link= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/a[text()='Link 1']"));
```

You then can write a code to drive the logic:

**Scenario 1:**

```
if(link.size()==2){
            link.get(1).click();
        }
```

**Scenario 2:** Your scenario 2 is not clear. Are you saying link will be present in DOM but not visible?
You can write something like this to check visibility.

```
link.get(0).isDisplayed()
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Best way to thanks is by accepting the answer and up voting :)